# How do I order by a function in LINQ query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing my first MVC application with Entity Framework. I have a table USERS and a table RESTRICTIONS

In my controller I wrote a function that returns the number of common restrictions between two users:

```
public int common_restrictions(int id1, int id2)
    {
        MyModel bd = new MyModel();
        int count= 0;

        var restrictions = from c in bd.RESTRICTIONS where c.ID_USER == id1 
        select c;
        var restrictions2 = from c in bd.RESTRICTIONS where c.ID_USER == id2 
        select c;

        foreach (var prop in restrictions)
        {
            var nr = restrictions2.Count(p => p.ID_PROP == prop.ID_PROP);
            if (nr != 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

The function works as it supposed to.
Now in another function in the same controller I want to sort the list of users in descending order of their common restrictions with a specific user (let's say user with the id 12). I got the list of users in a query but I don't know how to sort them after that

```
var query = from u in bd.USERS where u.ID != 12
                    select u;
// sort the list??
```

I've tried

```
        var query = from u in bd.USERS orderby(common_restrictions(u.ID, 
                    12)) select u;
```

but I get the following error message:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 common_restrictions (Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: The problem is your function outputs an integer value so you're basically telling it "order by 15" and LINQ doesn't understand what 15 is. You need to order by a column name. I'm not sure what the common restrictions are since you haven't given any explanation as to what their purpose is so I can't help you with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps if you don't want to include another property to your User object. And I think this following way is easier.

```
      var query = (from u in bd.USERS where u.ID != 12
                select u).ToList();
      var unSorteUsers = (from u in query  
                            select new
                            {

                                User = u,
                                CR = common_restrictions(u.ID,12)
                            });

        var sortedUsers = (from u in unSorteUsers

                           orderby u.CR
                           select new User
                           {

                               ID = u.User.ID,
                               //All other properties.
                           });
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message when I try to call common_restricions in unSorteUsers

Comment: I think I found the issue why it is not working. You need to call a ToList() to the first step ( I have changed the answer to reflect this)

Comment: It worked now! Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for the whole day. Why was this an error?

Comment: When you call the ToList() on the first method, it will bring all the data from the database. The rest of the methods can then work as normal because they know what common_restrictions is as it is defined in the code. But if you don't call the ToList() , EF will send the method to database where the db wouldn't know what common_restrictions is. That's the problem. It is called EF's delayed execution. ToList() forces instant execution otherwise it would be a delayed execution.